# How to transfer mouse and keyboard after migration

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, mouse, migration

So, both magic mouse and apple wireless keyboard left connected to my old MB Air and I transferred everything with migration assistant. Currently, both mouse and keyboard are paired to old Air and they aren't visible when I try to find them with new MB.

How can I transfer them? Should I contact Apple support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a old Magic Mouse and Keyboard.

You need to unpair them from your old MacBook Air first.   Then you can pair to your new MacBook.

From the [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201178) site

> 1. Make sure your device is powered on.
> 2. If the LED is blinking, your device is in Discoverable Mode. If the LED is steady, your device is paired with another item. Unpair the device, turn it off, and start again.
> 3. In the menu bar of your Mac, choose the Bluetooth icon, then
>    choose Open Bluetooth Preferences.
> 4. Your Mac scans for available Bluetooth devices.
> 5. When your device appears in the Bluetooth Preference Pane, click Pair.

In fact, you don't have to unpair it per se - so long as the old MBA isn't in range (off,  works) you should be able to pair it with no problems.

Comment: @patrix - seriously?  In the middle of answering?

Comment: What if I can't unpair them? Lost laptop for example.

Comment: When I looked at the answer it just consisted of one line. And I rarely look at the author when adding notices :-)

Comment: Lost MBA should be no problem.